# 301 redirect in laravel using.htacess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I am working on a project that was developed in core php. But now I have completed in laravel farmework. Now I want to redirect some pages to my laravel routes. Let's take an example.

```
www.example.com/Special-Feature.php?tid=262 //this core php url
```

Redirect to :

```
www.example.com/view/event/262 //my laravel url
```

Now if I hit this url:

```
www.example.com/Special-Feature.php?tid=262
```

it must go to my laravel url:

```
www.example.com/view/event/262
```

Can anyone help me how to do using htaccess?